# Why is the Add button for Page Role Editor is disabled even if the person is a friend?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add this person as a Page Role Editor so she can link the instagram account to the facebook account.
She is already an administrator and a friend. Why is the add button still disabled?[image]